# Spring Boot app working locally but not when deployed to Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, heroku

I have an issue with an app that has been working fine vor the past 7 months.
I pushed minimal frontend changes yesterday and since my app has been crashing on deployment.
First i thought it was something wrong with my database connection since this is what showed up first in the stacktrace:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I am using the JawsDB plugin so I checked everything there and when deploying locally the connection to the database works.

But in the stacktrace I have also found this with which i am not sure what to do about after searching for solutions to the error.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
2021-07-31T20:45:15.672985+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-07-31T20:45:15.672985+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:98) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-07-31T20:45:15.672987+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:220) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-07-31T20:45:15.672987+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:428) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-07-31T20:45:15.672987+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:336) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
2021-07-31T20:45:15.672988+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
2021-07-31T20:45:15.672988+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
2021-07-31T20:45:15.672988+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:329) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
```

Has anyone had experience with a similar issue or knows how to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just found the issue. It had to do with the dropped support for TLSv1 and TLSv1.1
in the latest update to the JDK in April 2021.

Adding ?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2 to my connection string fixed my issue.